# how to write a script in debian , which will kill/stop an application at a certain system time and start it at a certain system time?

Tags: linux

i want to write a script in debian , which will make an application stop at a certain system time . Before anyone thinks its a homework , it is not . My internet connection allows unlimited download only in a certain time period , so i would like to stop the torrent  application once the time period is over with .

Answer (score 1):

Cron (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) should be your friend here. Add 2 cron jobs to your crontab, one to start the script and one to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Check into `crontab -e` - you want something like this in there:

```
0   2   *   *   *   /path/to/yourtorrentclient start
0   6   *   *   *   /path/to/yourtorrentclient stop
```

if you want to turn it on at 02:00 every day, and turn it off at 06:00 every day, and assuming yourtorrentclient responds to arguments start and stop. Rewrite as needed.